# Mockito ArgumentMatcher to verify if arg value is contained in a certain collection

Tags: java, testing, mockito

Is there a way, using [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/) to define an expression like this?

```
when(mockObject.getValuesFor(in(1, 2, 3)).thenReturn(List.of(...)));
```

I can't find a method like `in()` among the ones defined in [`ArgumentMatchers`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/4.9.0/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html) and [`AdditionalMatchers`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/4.9.0/org/mockito/AdditionalMatchers.html), so I'd like to know which is a common way to achieve what I need.

**Note**
The method I'm mocking is declared like this:

```
List<Integer> getValuesFor(int arg) {...}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `intThat` gets close to what you need:

```java
when(mockObject.getValuesFor(intThat(x -> Set.of(1, 2, 3).contains(x))))
  .thenReturn(List.of(3, 4, 5));
```

In addition, you can extract a method producing inner `ArgumentMatcher<Integer>`, which would make your code look like

```java
when(mockObject.getValuesFor(intThat(isOneOf(1, 2, 3))))
  .thenReturn(List.of(3, 4, 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find one. So I use below workaround.

```
List list = List.of(1, 2, 3);
when(mockObject.getValuesFor(list).thenReturn(List.of(...)));

//do actual test method call

ArgumentCaptor<List> listCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.class(List.class);
verify(mockObject).getValuesFor(listCaptor.capture());

assertEquals(3, list.getValue().size());
assertEquals(1, list.getValue().get(0));
assertEquals(2, list.getValue().get(1));
assertEquals(3, list.getValue().get(2));
```

It essentially does the same thing. If same list was not passed as the method argument, test case will fail in assert statements.